# How to optimise this SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

This query is taking more then `4 minutes` and i want to make it run more quickly. Please provide any suggestions

```
SELECT *
FROM fact_acct zz
WHERE zz.C_AcctSchema_ID=1000000
AND zz.PostingType      ='A'
AND TRUNC(zz.DateAcct,'DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) <= Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(1001508)
AND Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) >= Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(1001508)
```

The function `Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val ()` is the cause of problem, it's run in this SQL for all queries, so it take the long time

because if i retire the last 2 lines ,this sql give results in `3 secondes`

So, any ideas to optimise that

Thanks

Comment: Try using between, will save 1 call to the function. Other then that, post the function. What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Primary key? Any indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without plan and ddl on table it would be only assumption.

First assumption

You have index on fact_acct.DateAcct, TRUNC(fact_acct.DateAcct,'DD') - will not use index
TRUNC(fact_acct.DateAcct,'DD') only trim hour/ minutes/ seconds part.
You can use

```
zz.DateAcct >= BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') <TO_DATE('2016-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Second assumption

Instead of

```
Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) <= Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(1001508)
```

put

```
 (select Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) from dual) <= (select Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(1001508) from dual)
```

Oracle doesn't execute this functions every time insted it uses caching mechanism. But be carefull! If you want that Oracle always executes  Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val, than you don't need this approach

Comment: I like this solution it work perfectly for me thanks #evgeniy-k

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is in **excessive number of function calls** and you are on a recent version of Oracle (I thing from 11g) you may profit from [subquery caching](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql#scalar-subquery-caching).

Simple rewrite all function calls to a subquery:

```
select *  from t1
where (select Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) from dual) between ...
```

This will work if you have a lot of records and a few `ACCOUNT_ID`s or if the `ACCOUNT_ID`s are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using a CTE like this would help:

```
WITH zz as (
      SELECT *
      FROM fact_acct zz
      WHERE zz.C_AcctSchema_ID = 1000000 AND
            zz.PostingType = 'A' AND AND
            zz.DateAcct >= TO_DATE('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            zz.DateAcct < TO_DATE('2016-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
     )
SELECT zz.*
FROM zz CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(1001508) as cv FROM dual) x
WHERE Z_Id_Cpt_To_Val(Account_ID) = x.cv;
```

For the CTE, you want an index on `fact_acct(C_AcctSchema_ID, PostingType, DateAcct)`.

Note:  The conditions in the `WHERE` clause concerning the function can be simplified to `=`, assuming that the function returns the same value for a given set of arguments.

If this doesn't help, you are going to need to dive into the function itself.